# Loading images from an array

Tags: arrays, image, actionscript-3

I'm trying to load an image from an array, but I can't figure out how to do so...

For text, it's good :

```
private var textArray:Array = [
{label:"text1", Type:"it's the text1"},
{label:"text2", Type:"it's the text2"}]
```

and the function setDisplay is showing one of the label in my textField

```
private function setDisplay(e:Event):void{
var fIndex:int = ac.aIndex;
txtField.htmlText = "<b>Title:</b><br /> "  +  fruitArray[fIndex].Type;
txtField.setTextFormat(titleFormat);
```

Now I can't figure out how to do the same thing for images...

I've tried that :

```
private var possibleSources:Array = [
{label:"Image1", Image: {url:"assets/smiley.jpg"}},
{label:"Image2", Image: {url:"assets/smiley2.jpg"}}];
```

and add in my SetDisplay function :

```
txtField.htmlText = "<b>Title:</b><br /> "  +  textArray[fIndex].Type + "<b>Images:</b><br /> "  +  possibleSources.Image;
```

The app is launching and I've got "it's the text1" for text1 and "it's the text2" for text2

But for "Images" I've got "undefined".... 
Do you know what's wrong ?

### Thank you for your help,

EDIT :

Thank you for your help.

Here's what I got so far :

```
private var possibleSources:Array = [
{label:"Image1", Image: {url:"assets/smiley1.jpg"}},
{label:"Image2", Image: {url:"assets/smiley2.jpg"}}];
private var textArray:Array = [
{label:"text1", Type:"It's the text1"},
{label:"text2", Type:"It's the text2"}]


private function setDisplay(e:Event):void{
it1.htmlText = "<b>Title :</b><br /> "  +  textArray[fIndex].Type +"<b>image :</b><br /> "  +  possibleSources[fIndex].Image.url;
```

And here's what I got as a result :

[image]

The smiley1.jpg is not here...

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in code where you access data about Image in the `possibleSources`:

Correct:

```
 trace(possibleSources[0].Image.url);
```

Also, if you want display image in the text field, url string isn't enough, read about [supported html tags](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText), and their format.

Comment: Thanks. So it's txtField.htmlText = "<b>Title :</b><br /> "  +textArray[fIndex].Type +"<b>Images:</b><br /> "  +  possibleSources[0].Image.url;   ?   And in order to display image : private var possibleSources:Array = [
{label:"A bloc", Image: <img src="smiley.jpg"/>}, ??

Comment: Yes, but don't forget iterate over possibleSources[index], not only `0` ;) and check quotes single/double when will you place your html code in Array

Comment: Hmmm so "possibleSources[fIndex].Image.url;"   and   private var possibleSources:Array = [
{label:"A bloc", Image: "<img src='smiley.jpg'/>"},  ? It's causing an error when it goes to text1 : 1069: Property url not found on String and there is no default value.

Comment: Yes, because you forgot `url` field. If you don't want it, code will be: `possibleSources[fIndex].Image`, if you want `url` property, add it... `{label:"Image1", Image: {url:"assets/smiley.jpg"}}`

Comment: Yes, because you forgot `img` tag... don't copy/paste my texts strictly, analyze information ;)